# How to apply many different rules on an object efficiently and using object oriented techniques using javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns

This is my first pass at this task i have. I need to update my UI based on the field. The field can be of different types. Here I am just checking for a memo or boolean type.

```
// UI Field Rule set.    

var UIFieldRules = {
    isMemo: function() {            
        return this.DataType === DataTypeKVP("Memo");
    },
    isBoolean: function() {
         return this.DataType === DataTypeKVP("Boolean");
    },
    MapToList: function() {
        if (UIFieldRules.isMemo.call(this) || UIFieldRules.isBoolean.call(this)) {
            console.log("memo or bool");
            console.log(UIFieldRules.isMemo.call(this));
            console.log(this);
            MAPTOLIST_SELECTOR.prop('disabled', true);
            return;
        } else {
            MAPTOLIST_SELECTOR.prop('disabled', false);
            console.log("UI field rules found memo");
        }
    }
};
```

I then call this object upon loading all the fields.

```
UIFieldRules.MapToList.call(field);
```

This works fine and satisfied the task, but now i need to apply more rules to the fields. (stop me if you heard this one before)

How can I get this set where i can just add a rule to a collection and have them all applied dynamically in **javascript**?

Update provide example:

```
function MapToList(field){
    isBoolean:function(){}
    isMemo : function(){}
    execute : function(){
        if (UIFieldRules.isMemo.call(this) || UIFieldRules.isBoolean.call(this)) {
            console.log("memo or bool");
            console.log(UIFieldRules.isMemo.call(this));
            console.log(this);
            MAPTOLIST_SELECTOR.prop('disabled', true);
            return;
        } else {
            MAPTOLIST_SELECTOR.prop('disabled', false);
            console.log("UI field rules found memo");
        }
    }
}
```

Then if i want to create more rules (which I do) should I create another object like the one above? Is there a best practice way of doing this in JS?

```
var rules = [];
rules.push(new MapToList(field));
rules.push(new RegExEnabled(field));

$.each(rules,function(item){
    item.execute();
});
```

Comment: What does "applied dynamically" mean?  I can't tell what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: dynamically, by way of them all having the same method ie execute. then when i pop them off I call item.execute() then the rule is applied.

Comment: I think you'll have to show more of something (maybe how you want the calling code to work) to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Instead of using `.call(this)` everywhere, you really should consider using parameters in your functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example approach is exactly fine. Create multiple objects that all implement the same interface, put them in a list, and then call a common method on each of them:

```
var rules = [MapToList, RegExEnabled];

rules.forEach(function(item){
    item.execute(field);
});
```

However, you might want to notice that you typically you don't need a constructor + `new` if your object is not stateful or does not have any parameterisation, a simple object literal is enough.
And similarly, if your shared interface boils down to a single `execute` method, what you actually want is not a list of objects but just a list of functions you can call. [It's not Java](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.de/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html) :-)